# Threading object issue

Tags: python, multithreading

I can't figure out why the threading object `threadObj` can't use `isAlive`, when I call `stop()`. The code is described below.

```
from threading import Thread

class workerThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self, _parent):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.parent = _parent
    self.active = False

  def run(self):
    while(self.active == False):
      print 'I am here'
    print 'and now I am here'

class imp():
  def __init__(self):
    self.threadObj = None

  def start(self):
    self.threadObj = workerThread(self)
    self.threadObj.start()

  def stop(self):
    if self.threadObj.isAlive() == True:
      print 'it is alive'
```

It says: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isAlive'

The calling code is descibed below:

```
from filename import imp

filename = imp()
if option == 'A':
  filename.start()
elif option == 'B':
  filename.stop()
```

Comment: Show us the call that's actually throwing the Exception, along with the full Traceback. `threadObj` is going to be `None` until you call `start()`. Did you call that before calling `stop()`?

Comment: yes, I did. I call start() first and it runs OK. When I call stop() I get the error. I added the calling code.

Comment: Is this code in some kind of loop where `option` is getting repeatedly provided by the user? Is `filename = imp()` inside that loop?

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce your error. Without being able to reproduce it, we are basically guessing blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that you mistakenly believe that your Threads are persistent between invocations of your program, which is not correct.  When you call `python callingCode.py A`, your program runs and executes the `if option == 'A'` block of code.  Then it exits, and your thread is cleaned up.  The second time, when you call `python callingCode.py B`, the thread is never created.

Comment: You might be correct. I think I know how to fix it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted:

```
from filename import imp

filename = imp() # you create an object here
if option == 'A':
  # if option is B, you are not launching the Thread
  # another words, this start() method will not be executed
  filename.start() 
elif option == 'B':
  # At this moment threadObj is None
  # because it wasn't started
  filename.stop()
```

I would suggest you to use `ptd` to find this type of bugs:

```
from filename import imp

filename = imp()

import ptb
ptb.set_trace()

if option == 'A':
  filename.start()
elif option == 'B':
  filename.stop()
```

Comment: But I always run option A first. And only after I call option B. That is the problem. Because I never call option B first.

Comment: Let's say that the calling code is run as `python callingCode.py A`. The code checks for the input parameter, provided when running the script. Now, after using paramter 'A', I run the script as `python callingCode.py B` and the error appears.